# Консольное приложение

Tags: delphi

Как в Delphi консольном приложении сделать невидимое окно, чтоб оно только в процессах было видно?

Comment: а зачем тогда консольное?

Answer (score 2):

a) Процесс может уничтожить консоль, которой он экслюзивно владеет функцией [`FreeConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683150(v=vs.85).aspx). Отсоединиться от консоли и уйти в фоновый режим а-ля UNIX в Windows NT невозможно.

б) Процесс может узнать дескриптор окна содержащего экранный буфер своей консоли функцией [`GetConsoleWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175(v=vs.85).aspx) и что-нибудь сделать с этим окном, например спрятать.

Answer (score 2):

Когда создаете Консольное приложение в Delphi 7, например, можете избавиться от строчки `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}`. Вследствие сего действия программа будет работать, но консоль выводиться не будет.

Comment: C определённой версии Delphi это перестало работать (в XE8 точно не работает). Теперь нужно зайти в **Project Options → Delphi Compiler → Linking** и установить параметр **Generate console application** в **false**

Answer (score -2):

Сделайте обыкновенное оконное приложение, а затем спрячьте его, вызвав `application.hide;`. Вуаля! Окно будет невидимо в любом случае! Только в процессах его можно запалить =)

**UPD:**
Если вам нужно просто выполнить определенный код, то можете воспользоваться такой прекрасной штукой, как инжект своей dll`ки в чужое адресное пространство - [Process Injection](http://www.vr-online.ru/?q=content/vnedrenie-dll-v-chuzhoe-adresnoe-prostranstvo-950)

Comment: Кстати, а как насчет инжекта в чужой поток?